# Creating a post edit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I currently use an `onEdit` function to assist in sorting a sheet.  The sheet sorts when a value is entered into column A but I would prefer the sheet to sort after all values in columns A-F have been entered, due to my lack of coding knowledge I need help on this.

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
var ASCENDING = true;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;

var activeSheet;

function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}
function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}

function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}

function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

Comment: Your code could be rewritten as `function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart==SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(e.range.getSheet());
  }
}` Can any the columns be blank? and still be considered entered.  Do you plan to enter each row of columns completely before moving on to another row?

Comment: Welcome. Two possibilities spring to mind. 1) enter data in Column A **after** you enter the data in Columns B-F. 2) trigger the sort by using a cell  other than in Column A-to-F; e.g., a checkbox in a header row. Would you please share a copy of the spreadsheet.

Comment: `getActiveCell()` does not always work correctly, I recommend you to make use of the event object: `editedCell=event.range;` and then you just need to define `SORT_COLUMN_INDEX=6` - provided you want the function to run after column F has been entered.

Comment: Thanks All for your answers: Tedinoz - I could do that but would be highly impractical (i'm also afraid that due to content in the sheet I can't share), Cooper & ziganotschka I have tried both of yours but I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 48, file "Code" - Not sure if you can help on this?  I wonder if there is more code that I should enter to define 'Range'?

Comment: The event.range is an event object that is only defined during the edit. This is why the code will give you an error if you try to run it manually. It will run correctly when fired automatically by an onEdit trigger.

Comment: Hello ziganotschka - I have tried that but it doesn't work, please see the code in the original question.  This is the whole code that I am using, it may be that there is more to it than the `onEdit` function - once finished the code as a whole will sort the sheet A-Z by column 1 only if all values in column 1-6 have been entered

Comment: "i'm also afraid that due to content in the sheet I can't share" @Gav You are severely limiting the ability of users to help you resolve this problem. No-one expects that you would include private or confidential information, nor that you would share your 'original' spreadsheet. A copy is fine, and you can edit the data to make it generic. However the data fields and types, the layout, and the code are of immense value to users in assisting you - if you chose to not to share, you run the risk of closing off avenues of support.

Comment: @Gav: For me your code works as intended. But keep in mind that onEdit() it works only when the edited cell is in column `B` (  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX)). Small annotation: You have a function `onInstall` - this is a trigger for installing of addons - is your code meant to be an Add-on?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry this is beyond me now.  I have now made a copy and cleared the sheet of data.... please see sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Bayn6z-th280iNfs_nI_DbYflyELIik53ClzF_4Hdk/edit?usp=sharing - if you could have a look at it and get it working then let me know once done that would be awesome.  I'm only a self taught editor and very inexperienced so would be glad of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need two column indexes

- a `SORT_COLUMN_INDEX` that specifies by which column the sheet shall be sorted and
- a `TRIGGER_COLUMN_INDEX` that specifies after the edit of which column `function autoSort` shall be called.

You can modify your code as following:

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
var TRIGGER_COLUMN_INDEX = 6;
var ASCENDING = true;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;

var activeSheet;

function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}
function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == TRIGGER_COLUMN_INDEX)  {
    Logger.log('column '+editedCell.getColumn()+' edited');
 autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
  else{
    Logger.log('other column edited');
  }
}

function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}

//Sure that you need the following function?
function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. If my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate if you consider to mark it as accepted.